# Erroneous Pulsetrain Timing

Tags: c, timer, arduino-uno, isr

I am having some trouble with a timer on my Arduino atmega328p-pu with 16MHz clock.

I have a really simply program with only one timer, two ISRs, and one pin.

The program does the following:
Iterates through the bits of 'sequence' and sets pin4 high or low respectively. However it doesnt set the bit high for the entire period, only 1/12 of it. What you see below is a single timer that counts up from 0 to 340. There is ISRB at 28, and then ISRA happens at 340, then it loops (that is what CTC mode does, loops after ISRA). ISRB always turns off the pin, and ISRA handles whether or not the pin should be high.

Now then the problem. All the timing works for each bit, but for some reason the loopover event causes the pulse spacing to SHORTEN. Yes shorten, not widen (which if anything was what I would expect because of extra clock cycles for executing the loop event).

it makes waveforms that look like this.

```
_|_|_|_|_ _ _ _ _|_|_|_||_|_|_|_ _ _ _
```

You can see that the problem resides in the junction between two packets, but the rest of the timing is good. I cant seem to track down why.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t sequence =0b111100001111;      // example data sequence
uint8_t packetlength = 12;
uint8_t index = 0;

void setup(){
    DDRD = 0xFF;      // all port D as input
    bitSet(DDRD, 4);  // board pin 4 output
    bitSet(PORTD, 4); // start high

    // initialize timer1 
    TCCR1A = 0;               // zeros timer control register
    TCCR1B = 0;          
    TCNT1  = 0;               // sets timer counter to 0

    OCR1A = 340;              // compare match register 340*62.5ns = 21.25us
    OCR1B = 28;               // 28*62.5ns = 1.75us

    TIMSK1 = 0;
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);   // CTC mode
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);    // CS10 no prescaler (use CS12 for 256 prescaler for testing)
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);  // enable timer compare A interrupt
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1B);  // enable timer compare B interrupt
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){          // controls bit repeat rate
    if (bitRead(sequence,index) == 1){
            bitSet(PORTD, 4);    //set high
    }
    index ++;
    if (index == packetlength){   //loop over when end reached.
        index = 0;
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPB_vect){          // controls duty cycle
    bitClear(PORTD, 4);          // set low
}

void loop(){
    //nothing
}
```

Edit: April 5. Scope photos demonstrating inter pulsetrain period shortening.
The important measurement value is BX-AX

Normal. 340 + 6 calculation clock cycles (best estimate from scope)
[image]

Bad. Timer only counting 284 cycles before interrupt is firing.
[image]
[image]

Also Bad, but not a huge problem. This pulse is far to wide to be reasonably explained by the clock cycles needed set the bit low. It appears to take 17, I would expect 3.
[image]

Comment: Smells like yet another case where variables shared with an ISR aren't protected from non-atomic access. And they aren't declared as volatile. In addition, writing to a GPIO register from a timer ISR could be similarly problematic if the same port is accessed from the rest of the program. These are all beginner-level bugs, fix them first and see if they solve the problem.

Comment: I thought volatile was only to be used when a variable could be changed externally, as in not via code but a pin being driven by something peripheral? However I tried it, it only seems to worsen timing accuracy by increasing calculation time.

Comment: Oh wait, those variables aren't shared with the rest of the application? This is the full code? In that case, nevermind, this isn't the problem. You should perhaps have declared them as `static` inside the ISR, less confusing for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why you should expect precise timing at the bit output. Interrupts begin after a delay once requested which will vary depending on instruction execution time for each instruction being run in whatever is being interrupted. I suspect (without seeing evidence in your report of the problem) that the variation you see is identical to instruction execution time variation.

If you want precise hardware output timing, you must either use never-interrupted programmed I/O or use the various flip-bit-upon-timer-compare features of the uP's hardware peripheral set.  The ISR can be used to set things up for the next compare, but not to directly flip output bits.

Once you've figured out how to setup the action to be performed by the hardware upon comparitor matches, it will be simpler to do it all in a single ISR.  That service routine can arrange for both the conditional bit set and the following unconditional bit clear.  You probably want the ISR to run during the lengthier part of the cycle so that latency in the actual running of *your* [a] ISR code does not cause the setup to be too late.

[a. In addition to your ISR code, the programming environment is causing some context save a restore to wrap what you wrote.  This can add execution cycles that might not be expected.  Auto-generated context save/restore often is extravagant about tucking away state so that naive programmers are not puzzled by strange foreground-background interactions. ]

Comment: I understand what you are saying about precise timing, that makes sense. However while it is something that is manifesting, precise timing is not something I need, only repeatability. So as long as the code executes periodically It is fine for now. However the code is not manifesting periodically. I will add some scope screenshots to the original post demonstrating the problem. I can handle a few extra clock cycles, but I am losing around 80.

Comment: By "precise", I meant only that the pin output transitions occur with repeatable timing counted in clock cycles.  I still think that your transition timing is being affected (or, made to vary from your expectation) by variations in the time that it takes your ISRs to actually begin running.  In other words, the code does not execute periodically in the sense of a constant period.  I have had fine results with the AtMega timer hardware (on an Arduino) programmed to run a variable output power converter.  The switch timing was "precise" (in the above sense) because I did it as I advised above.